# How I can fix anaconda vitrual enviroment problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I want to create a vitrual enviroment with conda but when I typed this "conda activate env_dlib"
it show this screen, can anyone tell me what's going on? And how I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Type `anaconda` in your search bar - IF you installed anaconda from official website you should also have installed anaconda shell - that's linux-mocking environment, where you can run virtual environments, and relevant python shell.

If you don't have it - just install the official distribution as per: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer ,i fixed, but not by your way,I really sure my anaconda is real,
i reboot my window, setup anaconda again,this time the destination folder's name
is "anaconda" instead for "anaconda3" and it's work,
(Till don't know what happen!)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRHWB.png)

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NOHn.png)